# Unable to pass Table Column name in xml path in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, select, case

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN D.DocumentCode='SA' THEN D.Name END AS 'IDProofofsigningauthority',
    CASE WHEN D.DocumentCode='GSTIN' THEN D.Name END AS 'GSTINRegistrationCopy',
    CASE WHEN D.DocumentCode='SA_T' OR D.DocumentCode='SA_E' THEN D.Name END AS 'IDProofofsigningauthority',
    CASE WHEN D.DocumentCode='PAN_T' THEN D.Name END AS 'PANCard',

    CONCAT ('https://abc/xyz/',"Filename") AS KYCDocumentUrl,

    CASE WHEN D.DocumentCode='GSTIN' THEN BPD.DocumentNumber END AS 'GSTINRegistrationCopyDocumentNumber',
    CASE WHEN D.DocumentCode='PAN_T' THEN BPD.DocumentNumber END AS 'PANCardDocumentNumber'
FROM 
    [dbo].[Documents] D 
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[BusinessPartyDcoument] BPD WITH (NOLOCK) ON D.Id = BPD.DocumentId
FOR XML PATH('Document')
```

This is my current output:

```
<Document>
    <GSTINRegistrationCopy>GSTIN Number</GSTINRegistrationCopy>
    <KYCDocumentUrl>https://abc/xyz/R1NUSU5fMTEy.pdf</KYCDocumentUrl>
    <GSTINRegistrationCopyNumber>1111</GSTINRegistrationCopyNumber>
</Document>
<Document>
    <PANCard>PAN Card</PANCard> 
    <KYCDocumentUrl>https://abc/xyz/UEFOX1RfNjFfOC8yLzIwMTkgN.pdf</KYCDocumentUrl>
    <PANCardDocumentNumber>BBBBB1111V</PANCardDocumentNumber>
</Document>
<Document>
    <IDProofauthority>ID Proof of signing authority</IDProofauthority>
    <KYCDocumentUrl>https://abc/xyz/U0FfNjFfOC8yLzIwMTkgNjo1.pdf</KYCDocumentUrl>
</Document>
```

This is my desired output:

```
    <GSTINRegistrationCopy>
        <DocumentName>GSTIN Number</DocumentName>
        <KYCDocumentUrl>https://abc/xyz/R1NUSU5fMTEy.pdf</KYCDocumentUrl>
        <DocumentNumber>1111</DocumentNumber>
    </GSTINRegistrationCopy>
    <PANCard>
        <DocumentName>PAN Card</DocumentName>
        <KYCDocumentUrl>https://abc/xyz/UEFOX1RfNjFfOC8yLzIwMTkgN.pdf</KYCDocumentUrl>
        <DocumentNumber>BBBBB1111V</DocumentNumber>
    </PANCard>
    <IDProofauthority>
        <DocumentName>ID Proof of signing authority</DocumentName>
        <KYCDocumentUrl>https://abc/xyz/U0FfNjFfOC8yLzIwMTkgNjo1.pdf</KYCDocumentUrl>
    </IDProofauthority>
```

I need to get document name instead of `<Document>` tag as shown in the output using SQL Server query. I need to get expected XML output using my query.

Please suggest how to get this done.

Comment: So what is your root node here? You don't appear to have one any more

Comment: Same sample data, as it appears in your database, would also be useful here.

Comment: As per @Larnu, please provide us with sample data to assist.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you want nested xml for each "case" in you "case when".
You can use "for xml path" and "for xml path, type" in nested queries.
But this solution has obvious problems with  performance, you can't use it for big amounts of data

```
declare @Document table 
(
    DocumentCode varchar(10),
    Name varchar(100),
    filename varchar(100),
    DocumentNumber varchar(20)
)

insert into @document values
('PAN_T','PAN Card','UEFOX1RfNjFfOC8yLzIwMTkgN.pdf','BBBBB1111V'),
('GSTIN','GSTIN Number','R1NUSU5fMTEy.pdf','1111'),
('SA','D Proof of signing authority','U0FfNjFfOC8yLzIwMTkgNjo1.pdf',NULL);

SELECT 

    CASE WHEN D.DocumentCode='GSTIN' THEN  
    (
        select D.Name 'DocumentName',
        'https://abc/xyz/'+d.Filename 'KYCDocumentUrl',
        D.DocumentNumber 'DocumentNumber'
        for xml path('') ,type

    ) END GSTINRegistrationCopy
    ,CASE WHEN D.DocumentCode='PAN_T' THEN  
    (
        select D.Name 'PANCard',
        'https://abc/xyz/'+d.Filename 'KYCDocumentUrl',
        D.DocumentNumber 'DocumentNumber'
        for xml path('') ,type

    ) END PANCard
    ,CASE WHEN D.DocumentCode='SA' THEN  
    (
        select D.Name 'DocumentName',
        'https://abc/xyz/'+d.Filename 'KYCDocumentUrl'
        for xml path('') ,type

    ) END IDProofauthority

FROM 
    @Document D 
FOR XML PATH('')
```

Answer (score 0):

(Similar to vitalygolub's answer...)

Given source data structured like the OPs:

```sql
if object_id('[dbo].[Documents]') is not null drop table [dbo].[Documents];
if object_id('[dbo].[BusinessPartyDcoument]') is not null drop table [dbo].[BusinessPartyDcoument];

select * into [dbo].[Documents]
from (values
    (1, 'GSTIN', 'GSTIN Number'),
    (2, 'PAN_T', 'PAN Card'),
    (3, 'SA', 'ID Proof of signing authority')
) Src ([Id], [DocumentCode], [Name]);

select * into [dbo].[BusinessPartyDcoument]
from (values
    (1, 'R1NUSU5fMTEy.pdf', '1111'),
    (2, 'UEFOX1RfNjFfOC8yLzIwMTkgN.pdf', 'BBBBB1111V'),
    (3, 'U0FfNjFfOC8yLzIwMTkgNjo1.pdf', null)
) Src ([DocumentId], [Filename], [DocumentNumber]);
```

The following SQL:

```sql
SELECT
    (
    SELECT
        D.Name AS 'DocumentName',
        DocumentUrl AS 'KYCDocumentUrl',
        BPD.DocumentNumber AS 'DocumentNumber'
    WHERE D.DocumentCode='GSTIN'
    FOR XML PATH('GSTINRegistrationCopy'), TYPE
    ),
    (
    SELECT
        D.Name AS 'DocumentName',
        DocumentUrl AS 'KYCDocumentUrl',
        BPD.DocumentNumber AS 'DocumentNumber'
    WHERE D.DocumentCode='PAN_T'
    FOR XML PATH('PANCard'), TYPE
    ),
    (
    SELECT
        D.Name AS 'DocumentName',
        DocumentUrl AS 'KYCDocumentUrl'
    WHERE D.DocumentCode='SA'
    FOR XML PATH('IDProofofsigningauthority'), TYPE
    )
FROM 
    [dbo].[Documents] D 
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[BusinessPartyDcoument] BPD WITH (NOLOCK) ON D.Id = BPD.DocumentId
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT DocumentUrl = CONCAT('https://abc/xyz/', "Filename")
) DU
FOR XML PATH('');
```

Outputs the following XML:

```xml
<GSTINRegistrationCopy>
    <DocumentName>GSTIN Number</DocumentName>
    <KYCDocumentUrl>https://abc/xyz/R1NUSU5fMTEy.pdf</KYCDocumentUrl>
    <DocumentNumber>1111</DocumentNumber>
</GSTINRegistrationCopy>
<PANCard>
    <DocumentName>PAN Card</DocumentName>
    <KYCDocumentUrl>https://abc/xyz/UEFOX1RfNjFfOC8yLzIwMTkgN.pdf</KYCDocumentUrl>
    <DocumentNumber>BBBBB1111V</DocumentNumber>
</PANCard>
<IDProofofsigningauthority>
    <DocumentName>ID Proof of signing authority</DocumentName>
    <KYCDocumentUrl>https://abc/xyz/U0FfNjFfOC8yLzIwMTkgNjo1.pdf</KYCDocumentUrl>
</IDProofofsigningauthority>
```